# Hide multiple inputs with a single function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to hide an input, I do that in this way:

Javascript:

```
$scope.show= true;
$scope.showOrNot= function () {
    $scope.show= !$scope.show;
}
```

In my html:

```
<div class="item" ng-click="showOrNot()">
     <p><b>blablabla</b></p>
</div>
<li class="item" ng-hide="show">
    <input type="text">
</li>
```

The showOrNot function is called when I click in the div before the specific input.

If I have 20 inputs in my page, I have to write in my javascript 20 times same functions. Have you an idea how to resolve more efficiently?

Comment: please explain what you want to happen...in more detail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a key to the showOrNot function and map the key to a show/hide object on the scope:

```js
  angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('exampleController', function($scope) {

    $scope.show = {};
    $scope.showOrNot = function(key) {
      $scope.show[key] = !$scope.show[key];
    };

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="exampleController">

    <div class="item" ng-click="showOrNot('item')">
      <p><b>blablabla 1</b>
      </p>
    </div>
    <li class="item" ng-hide="show.item">
      <input type="text">
    </li>

    
    
    <div class="item" ng-click="showOrNot('item2')">
      <p><b>blablabla 2</b>
      </p>
    </div>
    <li class="item" ng-hide="show.item2">
      <input type="text">
    </li>
    
    
    <div class="item" ng-click="showOrNot('item3')">
      <p><b>blablabla 3</b>
      </p>
    </div>
    <li class="item" ng-hide="show.item3">
      <input type="text">
    </li>
    
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That work, I have just a problem. By default ng-hide is false and I want that by default is true

Comment: Have you tried adding a ! to the ng-hide? Like this: `ng-hide="!show.item2"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#In_an_in%E2%80%93line_event_handler) as parameter and evaluate the value in the function.

```
<div class="item" ng-click="showOrNot(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply in ng-Class concept in the input field. This class variable based your logic show and hide the all input field.

http://welcometolearntoday.blogspot.in/2015/01/ng-class-using-angularjs-example.html